# Asymptotic behavior of matrix elements of fractional Laplacian on integers

Tags: fourier-analysis, asymptotics

Let $\alpha\in (0,2)$ be fixed and $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Is there an elementary argument ensuring the existence of positive constants $c,C$ such that for all large enough $n$, we have
$$\frac{c}{n^{1+\alpha}} \leq \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} (1-\cos x)^{\frac{\alpha}{2}} e^{inx}\, dx\leq \frac{C}{n^{1+\alpha}}.$$